# Sorting posts by week/month/all time

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, filter

So I have managed to sort my posts with some basic settings. I want to change this from date-asc, date-dec, comments etc week, month, all time. I also was hoping to incorporate the following code which would sort the top voted posts only, instead of all posts

```
meta_key=votes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=10
```

My working top rated page at the moment, which sorts my date-asc, title etc:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['o']) && $_GET['o'] != '')
      {
          $order = $_GET['o'];
          switch($order)
          {
            case 'date-asc': $orderby = 'order=ASC';
                        $msg = 'Date Ascending';
                          break;

            case 'date-desc': $orderby = 'order=DESC';
                        $msg = 'Date Descending(default)';
                          break;

            case 'date-mod': $orderby = 'orderby=modified';
                            $msg = 'Date Modified';
                           break;

            case 'title-asc': $orderby = 'orderby=title&order=ASC';
                            $msg = 'Title A-Z';
                            break;

            case 'title-desc': $orderby = 'orderby=title&order=DESC';
                            $msg = 'Title Z-A';
                            break;

            case 'comment': $orderby = 'orderby=comment_count';
                            $msg = 'Comment Count';
                            break;
          }
      }
      else
      {
          $orderby = 'order=DESC';
          $msg = 'Date Descending (default)';
      }
?>

<div id="content">

<div id="sorter-container">


<h2 id="sort-heading">Posts ordered by:<?php echo $msg; ?></h2>
    <select id="order-by">
        <option value="date-desc" <?php echo (!isset($order) || $order == '' || $order == 'date-desc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Desc. (default)</option>
        <option value="date-asc" <?php echo ($order == 'date-asc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Asc</option>
        <option value="date-mod" <?php echo ($order == 'date-mod')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Date Modified</option>
        <option value="title-desc" <?php echo ($order == 'title-desc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Title Desc.</option>
        <option value="title-asc" <?php echo ($order == 'title-asc')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Title Asc.</option>
        <option value="comment" <?php echo ($order == 'comment')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>Comments Count</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var orderby = jQuery('#order-by');
            var str;
            orderby.change(function(){
                str = jQuery(this).val();
                 window.location.href = "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/top-rated/?o="+str;
            });
  </script>
```

**EDIT2:**
Ok, so here is what I have, it no longer works, so I just continued and added week/month/alltime to where I think it should go (I know its not correct, but I wasnt sure how to limit the sort to just 7 days etc.

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['o']) && $_GET['o'] != '')
      {
          $order = $_GET['o'];
          switch($order)
          {
            case 'week': $orderby = 'meta_key=votes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&WEEK&posts_per_page=10';
                        $msg = 'This Week (default)';
                          break;

            case 'month': $orderby = 'meta_key=votes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&MONTH&posts_per_page=10';
                            $msg = 'This Month';
                           break;

            case 'alltime': $orderby = 'meta_key=votes_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&ALLTIME&posts_per_page=10';
                            $msg = 'All Time';
                            break;
      else
      {
          $orderby = 'order=DESC';
          $msg = 'This Week (default)';
      }
?>

<div id="content">

<div id="sorter-container">


<h2 id="sort-heading">Posts ordered by:<?php echo $msg; ?></h2>
    <select id="order-by">
        <option value="week" <?php echo (!isset($order) || $order == '' || $order == 'week')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>This Week (default)</option>
        <option value="month" <?php echo ($order == 'month')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>This Month</option>
        <option value="alltime" <?php echo ($order == 'alltime')? 'selected="selected"':''; ?>>All Time</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i edited the OP a little. Just want to sort my top rated posts by week, month, all time instead of what its currently at (date-des, date-asc, title, comments etc)

Comment: I thought so, Where do you get stuck? All code seems to be in place. You only need to change the `<option value"">` and the `case` statements. You already figured out the `orderby=meta_value_num` which is a point people tend to get stuck on.

Comment: I cant take credit for getting this far by myself, I found a great tutorial haha :) However, when trying to change my options to week, month...I wasnt sure what I have to actually change. I checked google, wordpress codex, php help...I then and got lost/confused.

Comment: you aren't a coder are you? You know where to look no or do you need more help?

Comment: What gave it away :) No, not a coder, but im learning bits as I work my way through. Even if I see how to do one as an example, I think I could work the rest out. Thanks for keeping this thread going janw, appreicated.

Comment: I have tried messing around with the option value and see that is where I would post the meta_key=votes_count, but how can I get it based on the not only the vote count, desc AND for 7 days? That is where Im failing. Thanks

Comment: can you update teh question and code?

Comment: Hi Janw, I updated the OP with the updated code. It no longer works, Im guessing its orderby, but Im not sure how to limit it for just a week/month etc. I checked this post over the weekend while on my phone, but didnt have the details to reply...so had to wait until I returned to work. Sorry about the hold up.

Comment: We all had weekend:P. The meta key `votes_count` will only keep track of its votes. It doesn't appear to keep track of when the vote is cast. As it stands right now it's impossible to check

Comment: Ahhhh...damn, thats a bummer...and Im guessing add this functionality will be no easy task (for a newbie like me?). I will look into getting some ftp client for my android phone, im sure there are loads (I see there is a wordpress app too). So my apologies once again

Comment: it's not impossible to do but I it's not easy. And practically impossible for someone with no programming knowledge.

Comment: maybe a plugin would be a good idea for this. Out of intrest, could you describe what i would need to do? I might be able to find a post a post in a forum, or maybe some tutorial. I got this far, need to keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments of the question your current code base does not make it possible to do what you want.

[wp-postratings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/) Can do exactly like you want in the faq there is a question **To Display Highest Rated Post Within A Given Period**.
Take a look there you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: I tried that plugin before, but I might need to give it a 2nd look. Im currently downloading a PHP Fundamentals tutorial, hopefully that will help too. The only thing is that since getting the rating system up and running, Im now quite found of it...would it be worthwhile starting another thread, trying to modify what I have?

Comment: Okay, the problem is youre not a coder. I recommend getting a coder involved.